# In VB.Net Winforms is there a general solution to prevent a child control from painting outside of the parent control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a parent control that contains 1...N child controls.  When I horizontally scroll the parent, the child control scroll as well.

I would like to clip the child controls to the bounds of the parent control.  When I set a clip region to the bounds of the parent control, the child control paint still renders outside of the parent.

Is there a way to clip a child control to the bounds of the parent control?

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.  Post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have the clipping working now - but probably not is a best-practice approach.  The approach is:

Answer (score 0):

I have the clipping working now - but is probably not the best-practice approach. The approach is I used is below.

But I am wondering about the useage of the UserControl.Region property in a Paint event handler vs. the Graphics.SetClip and Graphics.Clip in the same handler.  The UserControl.Region property seems to work well - but the Graphics.SetClip and Clip had no effect.

My guess is that the UserControl.Region property uses control coordinates and the Graphics.SetClip and Clip expect a different coordinate system. Is this correct?

Approach:

1. Compute a clipping rectangle in control coordinates.  In my case I want to clip my custom control to a DevExpress XtraChart XYDiagram (so that my control does not spill outside of the plot area).
2. In my control event handler, set the Region property to the clipping rectangle computed in step 1.

I'm also curious about ways to minimize flicker during paint events. Any comments would be appreciated.