# How do I clip a WinForms UserControl to the bounds of a parent control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have a user control that I wish to clip to the bounds of a parent control.

I can do this by setting the Region property of the user control to a rectangle that bounds the visible portion of the user control in the parent control.

However, this introduces a great deal of flicker and seems to go into a perpetual repaint mode.  So my current method is not correct.

Could anyone point me to the best practice and most performant approach to clip a user control to the bounds of a parent control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In VB.Net Winforms is there a general solution to prevent a child control from painting outside of the parent control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284580/in-vb-net-winforms-is-there-a-general-solution-to-prevent-a-child-control-from-p)

Comment: I have also set the DoubleBuffered flag to True.  The user control is currently nothing more than a UserControl with a visible border. It appears that after the Region changes, the control repaints itself several times.  Is there a way to validate the UserControl Region so that it is only repainted once?